# can I nest virtualenvs?

Tags: python, virtualenv

is it possible to nest 2 virtualenvs?

I would like to have a base virtualenv and then a more specific virtualenv that accesses all the packages from the base virtualenv and then has its own.

Any hint appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I just found this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538675/can-a-virutalenv-inherit-from-another, but it is not really creating 2 virtualenvs, is there a better solution where somebody can either load the base virtualenv or the more specific virtualenv?

Comment: Why not just include all the packages in the base virtualenv?

Comment: @Jordan sometimes it could be useful to have the same base layer of packages, with different versions of other packages spread across the nested virtualenvs.

Comment: Then maybe you could just use multiple requirements.txt files. 1 for the base level, and then another for more particular items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this isn't currently possible. There is a feature request and a patch for the functionality out there though:

https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/33

Answer (score 1):

You can run in trouble when running python scripts of a virtualenv as subprocesses of another virtualenv. I've found useful to remove from the environment of the subprocess PYTHONPATH and BUILDOUT_ORIGINAL_PYTHONPATH.