# How can I copy Python with all its packages from one PC to another

Tags: python, installation, pip, package

Before someone close this question for being duplicate please note that I have tried several solutions from stack overflow and nothing seems to work. Following are the solutions I tried:

1. [Transfer Python setup across different PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033753/transfer-python-setup-across-different-pc/11034515)
2. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24093/how-to-clone-python-working-environment-on-another-machine

Now my question.

I made a few machine learning algorithms on my laptop during lockdown. (It gave me hard time back then as well to install proper tensorflow + keras packages). Now, after lockdown ends here, I want to run those algos on my lab PCs but I get errors for not having proper packages.

In short, I just want to clone my laptop based python and all other packages to my lab computer.

PS. I tried to install Keras package, but it ask me to downgrade my Python which I cannot due to apparent restriction from my university network.

Comment: you probably want to use docker

Comment: While I cannot directly answer your question, when I ran into the same issue, I decided it was time to migrate for more repeatable setups. Use Pipenv for dependencies, and have your whole application running on Docker, which means that you'd be able to run your application on any system where it's possible to install docker, with no more problems

Answer (score 1):

Try to collect all the packages through this command from the current machine: $ pip freeze > requirements.txt : and then install on another new machine: pip install -r requirements.txt :
link:  https://blog.usejournal.com/why-and-how-to-make-a-requirements-txt-f329c685181e

link : https://intellipaat.com/community/31672/how-to-use-requirements-txt-to-install-all-dependencies-in-a-python-project

**second solution**::::
a simple one find your interpreter's local directory conda env locations and copy your project interpreter [image]in my case here are my interpreters located on this location.

link: [Anaconda Python: where are the virtual environments stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709497/anaconda-python-where-are-the-virtual-environments-stored)

Comment: Tried that already. Mentioned in one of the links I shared. Does not work for me sadly :(