# what url should I authorize to use pip behind a firewall?

Tags: python, pip, firewall

I have a server, onto which I want to use Python, that is behind a company firewall. I do not want to mess with it and the only thing I can do is to make a firewall exception for specific URL/domains.

I also want to access packages located on PYPI, using pip or easy_install. Therefore, do you know which URL should I ask to be listed in the exception rules for the firewall, except *.pypi.python.org?

Comment: What do you mean `except *.pypi.python.org`? That's the PyPI URL.

Comment: @katrielalex: PyPI is the *metadata* index, and although most packages have been uploaded to PyPI as well, this is *optional*. Loads of other packages are served from their own domains. `pip` will look up the download location(s) and contact the correct location to get it. That can by *anywhere* on the internet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I agree. I read the OP's statement `located on PYPI` as `hosted on PyPI`, because clearly there's no way to add a firewall rule "allow anything linked by PyPI".

Comment: Alright, my bad. I wasn't aware the upload to PyPI is optional *only*, even though I have noticed that pip bounced on other servers for download... Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to open up your firewall to the download locations of any package you need to install, or connect to a proxy server that has been given access.

Note that the download location is not necessarily on PyPI. The Python package index is a metadata service, one that happens to also provide storage for the indexed packages. As such, not all packages indexed on PyPI are actually *downloaded* from PyPI, the download location could be anywhere on the internet.

I'd say you start with opening `pypi.python.org`, then as individual package installions fail, check their PyPI page and add the download location listed for those.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Do you think a good alternative would be to do `export PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=$HOME/.pip_download_cache`, create a virtual env on a machine that has access to the internet, do `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and copy this download cache to the isolated machine that have access to pypi (so that I can check that there are no newer versions if newer requirements.txt authorize newer package versions?

Comment: @Marc-OlivierTiteux: That could work, yes. Another alternative would be to set up a [PyPI mirror](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.eggproxy) (acts as a caching proxy for requested packages).

Comment: I ended up using something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12147405/493211 (made on a server that has access to the web) and then only the second line for when I am the isolated machine. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same restriction. Is there a way to check the location of a package?

Comment: @paolof89: add the `-v` switch (can be added multiple times) to increase the verbosity of pip: `pip install -v ...` and look at what that tells you. It'll report all URLs it tries to connect to.

Answer (score 20):

I've solved it adding these domains to the firewall whitelist:

- pypi.python.org
- pypi.org
- pythonhosted.org

Comment: Also need `files.pythonhosted.org`. Some packages need this like ansible.