# latest advice on exceptions to companies firewall to allow download of python packages

Tags: python

I am a python newbie and currently explore what I would have to tell my company's security department to allow us to add python packages. Given [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277088/what-url-should-i-authorize-to-use-pip-behind-a-firewall) sugestion I could ask them to add an exception for pypi.python.org but I do not think that this server hosts all potential packages. If this is still true, are there now some kind of package aggregator servers similar to R CRAN servers? We can add packages to R without problem as R CRAN servers were added to the list of excpetions. Any up-to-date feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) has a python distro with its own package manager. I have no idea if its a single site suitable for firewall exception, but worth a look.

Comment: I've used [devpi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/devpi) ([docs](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/)) for similar reasons. In my case, I let the devpi server through a private network so it could see the world but other servers were still restricted.