# Python pip: What are the ports and IP address ranges in use / that need to be allowed

Tags: python, pip, firewall, network-traffic

I have a Python Azure Function that is integrated in a subnet in a virtual network. Additionally there is a network security group associated to the subnet that controls inbound and outbound traffic to / from the subnet.

The requirement is to restrict traffic as much as possible what requires me to set rules that restrict the ports and destination addresses (for outbound traffic).

Network Security Groups need IP(s/ranges) - urls (as discussed here: [what url should I authorize to use pip behind a firewall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277088/what-url-should-i-authorize-to-use-pip-behind-a-firewall)) can't be specified.

Which ports and IP(s/ranges) are used by pip?

Thanks

Comment: I would assume `https` (and maybe `http`). URLs: `pypi.org`, `files.pythonhosted.org` at least.

Comment: Thanks but as written urls are not possible. I need IP(s/ranges).

Comment: I would recommend asking them directly: https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues

Comment: The IP address assigned to a URL is subject to change at any time.  That's why there are domain name resolution servers.

Comment: Both `pypi.org` and `files.pythonhosted.org` are at a CDN (content-delivery network) to distribute load, You cannot know IP ranges as they're constantly changing.

Comment: I am not sure if everyone is reading what I wrote - so here again: given the current set up I can't specify urls. And e.g. in the Azure context there are defined IP ranges for certain services. I will ask them directly. Thanks

Comment: When you come here to ask questions that don't have a sensible answer, don't be upset when we can't answer them.

Comment: @Mark: I am not upset because I don't get an answer, I am just a bit confused why people coming up with urls when I explicitly write that I can't use urls (given the current setup). And I don't fully understand why there is no sensible answer (like "this is not possible" or "there are the following IP ranges"...)

Comment: I don't know enough about the way pip works to state definitively that "this is not possible", but knowing how the internet works I have a reasonably strong opinion.  @phd brings up a good point too, if they've offloaded the hosting of those files it really may be impossible for *anybody* to give you an IP range.