# Does pip only use PyPI or does it use other domains to find packages?

Tags: pip, pypi, python-packaging

I know that by default, pip uses PyPI to look for packages. I would like to know if there are other domains other than PypI that pip uses.

Comment: Please see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#description.

Comment: It feels to me like this question is out of scope for StackOverflow... Also this feels like this is very easy to figure out for someone who actually wants to know... Anyway... -- That I know of: the distribution files found on PyPI are actually served from `files.pythonhosted.org`, so that is at least this additional domain that _pip_ uses out of the box.

Comment: If you're looking how to configure your firewall: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67416056/7976758

Comment: I don't think this question is out of scope. Many companies for security reasons block sites. I need to list the lists that pip could use. I only got Pypi so I'm just asking the community whether or not I had missed something. So this question might be useful for anyone working with Python in a company that blocks internet access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIP Can install [from](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#description)

- PyPI
- VCS project URL
- Local project directories
- Local or remote source archives

to run from a local passage you can input `pip install /opt/mypackage`

Finally, run `pip install --help` to see all installation options

Answer (score 2):

PIP can install from many different sources. You can find the whole list [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/)

You can also setup your own Python package repository and configure pip to install from there.