# Python setuptools: install pacakge dependencies from a local repository

Tags: python, python-2.7, dependencies, setuptools, pypi

The dependencies of A Python package are declared in a file called `setup.py`, under the key 
`install_requires`, e.g.:

```
  install_requires=[
      'Flask >= 0.10.1',
      'requests >= 2.2.1',
      'jsonschema >= 2.3.0',
      'nose >= 1.3.0',
      'behave >= 1.2.4'
  ]
```

The dependencies for tests are declared under the key `tests_requires`.

When the package is installed (by using `python setup.py install`), the dependencies are fetched from The Python Package index ([pypi.python.org](https://pypi.python.org/)).

**Is there a way to install the package, and let it fetch its dependencies from a local package repository, like [pypiserver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver)?**

This way I can cache frequently-used packages, and install internal packages that do not exist in PyPi.

I am probably looking for something like:

```
python setup.py install 
      --repo http://127.0.0.1:8000/localrepo 
      --fallback-repo http://pypi.python.org
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PIP cache you could install the dependencies more one time.

Adding to `~/.bash_profile` the next line:

```
export PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=$HOME/.pip_download_cache
```

See the next link https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806458/3380763