# How to install Ruby Gems, also caching them along the way?

Tags: python, ruby, caching, installation, bundler

When using Python with pip we can specify an environment variable which says to also download the packages to a cache location: "[How do I install from a local cache with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806448/how-do-i-install-from-a-local-cache-with-pip)".

```
export PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=$HOME/.pip_download_cache
pip install numpy
```

How can we do the same for bundler as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gem` command line tool automatically caches gems. From [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Installer.html):

> Gem::Installer does the work of putting files in all the right places on the filesystem including unpacking the gem into its gem dir, installing the gemspec in the specifications dir, **storing the cached gem in the cache dir**, and installing either wrappers or symlinks for executables.

Comment: `gem pristine` takes advantage of the cache to rebuild gems. It's very convenient if you upgrade something in the system that breaks Ruby.