# Unable to pip inside virtual env

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to install django-rq inside my virtual env  but I am encountering this error:

pip install django-rq

```
Collecting rq>=0.3.4 (from django-rq)
  Using cached rq-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Hash of the package https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/r/rq/rq-0.5.1- py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=45418bdc995c394b4293180a4c29cb88 (from 
https://pypi.python.org/simple/rq/) (e9d365b19b099235441599de78b25042)   doesn't match the expected hash 45418bdc995c394b4293180a4c29cb88!
  Bad md5 hash for package https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/r/rq/rq-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=45418bdc995c394b4293180a4c29cb88 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rq/)
```

I tried installing it outside the virtual environment and it worked perfectly fine. But I am not sure why it is not installing inside virtual environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like pip is trying to install the module form local cache, please refer here for more details: [How do I install from a local cache with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806448/how-do-i-install-from-a-local-cache-with-pip)

Try using something like this:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir django-rq
```