# Pip install from local index fails

Tags: python, pip, pip2pi

I am trying to install packages with pip from a local index that I have created with pip2pi. But I am in no way able to install these packages to a virtual environment. Basically I just followed the steps of the [pip2pi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip2pi/0.6.8) documentation or the third answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806448/how-do-i-install-from-a-local-cache-with-pip) stackoverflow post.

I started out downloading the required packages from pip to a local directory:

```
#download package
pip2tgz /d/temp/packages pyyaml==3.11
#create index    
dir2pi /d/temp/packages
```

Afterwards I created a new virtual environment for python and tried installing the package

```
#Create environment
virtualenv /d/temp/myenv
#Activate environment
source /d/temp/myenv/Scripts/activate
#Install pyyaml
pip install --index-url=file:///d/temp/packages/simple pyyaml==3.11
```

Installing pyyaml (or any other package for that matter) always fails:

```
Collecting pyyaml==3.11
←[33m  DEPRECATION: Failed to find 'pyyaml' at file:///d/temp/packages/simple/pyyaml/.
It is suggested to upgrade your index to support normalized names as the
name in /simple/{name}.←[0m
←[31m  Cannot fetch index base URL file:///d/temp/packages/simple/←[0m
←[31m  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyyaml==3.11 (from versions: )←[0m
←[31mNo matching distribution found for pyyaml==3.11←[0m
(myenv)
```

I am just trying to install the same version that I downloaded. I also tried using different flags like passing `--normalize-package-names` to `dir2pi` or calling `pip install` with arguments `--no-index` and `--find-links /d/temp/packages/`.

Note: I am working on a Windows machine, from within gitbash.
`Pip` and `pip2pi` are updated to the newest version (7.1.0 and 0.6.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although gitbash usually expects paths in the format

```
/d/temp/packages
```

in this case, you will have to specify it in Windows style

```
/d:/temp/packages
```

The following will work as expected:

```
pip install --index-url=file:///d:/temp/packages/simple pyyaml==3.11
```