# Where is pip cache folder?

Tags: python, pip

Where is the Python pip cache folder? I had an error during installation and now reinstall packages using cache files. Where is that directory? I want to take a backup of them for installation in the future. Is it possible?

For example, I have this one

```
Using cached cssselect-0.9.1.tar.gz
```

I searched google for this directory but nothing I saw, is learning how to install from a folder, I want to find the default cache directory.

**And another question:** Will these cache files stay in that directory, or will they be removed soon?

Comment: It depends on the OS.

Comment: windows @MartinKonecny

Comment: I believe it is in `~\AppData\Local\pip\cache` on Windows.

Comment: there are many files with unclear names like '0f4017d43a13156e41129019e85a69fcc2dd34e6904ed88395bb5451'... can i find exactly 'cssselect-0.9.1.tar.gz' file ??? @fredrik

Comment: A cache is not always human-readable, as in this case.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4806448/1959808

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache

Answer (score 146, accepted):

It depends on the operating system.

With **pip 20.1** or later, you can find it with:

```
pip cache dir
```

For example with macOS:

```
$ pip cache dir
/Users/hugo/Library/Caches/pip
```

Docs:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_cache/
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching

Comment: Yeah ... It's an old question ( about 4 years :D )

Comment: Old but still relevant! https://github.com/hugovk/pypistats/pull/105/commits/36d734b4f1266466357b656accffb48566c61e38

Comment: See also the `PIP_CACHE_DIR` environment variable to set this directory.

Comment: `$ pip install --no-deps --force black`  
Downloading black-22.3.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
Successfully installed black-22.3.0
`$ pip install --no-deps --force black`  
Using cached black-22.3.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
Successfully installed black-22.3.0
`$ pip cache list`  
Nothing cached.

Answer (score 172):

> The default location for the cache directory depends on the Operating System:
>
> ### Unix
>
> ~/.cache/pip and it respects the XDG_CACHE_HOME directory.
>
> ### macOS
>
> ~/Library/Caches/pip
>
> ### Windows
>
> <CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA>\pip\Cache
>
> ### Wheel Cache
>
> pip will read from the subdirectory wheels within the pip cache directory and use any packages found there. [snip]
>
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#caching

The location of the cache directory can be changed via the command line option [`--cache-dir`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#cmdoption-cache-dir).

Comment: <CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA> == %LOCALAPPDATA%

Comment: %LOCALAPPDATA%\pip\Cache

Comment: `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` is empty. `find ~/.cache/pip | grep -i tensor` shows `tensorflow_determinism` and `silence_tensorflow` wheels, but not `tensorflow-gpu`. Yet `pip install tensorflow-gpu` says `Using cached https://.../tensorflow_gpu-2.0.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl`. Where else should I look for this file?

Comment: (I also downloaded `tensorflow_gpu-2.0.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl` and checked for duplicates using `fdupes`, but could not find any...)

Answer (score 29):

Pythonic and cross-platform way:

```
import pip
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

if LooseVersion(pip.__version__) < LooseVersion('10'):
    # older pip version
    from pip.utils.appdirs import user_cache_dir
else:
    # newer pip version
    from pip._internal.utils.appdirs import user_cache_dir

print(user_cache_dir('pip'))
print(user_cache_dir('wheel'))
```

Under the hood, it normalizes paths, manages different locations for exotic and ordinary operating systems and platforms, performs Windows registry lookup.

It may worth mentioning, if you have different Python versions installed, 2.x'es and 3.x'es, they all do share the same cache location.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.utils'` , pip 10.0.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: If you wanted `pip`'s own cache directory you could also just use `from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR` or `python -c "from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR; print(USER_CACHE_DIR)"` if you were grabbing things in a script, etc.

Comment: Please do not go into `_internal` and fetch values. pip's internals are not meant to be used like a library and subject to change. `pip cache dir` on pip 20.1 and above is the best way to get this value.

Answer (score 10):

You can backup the associated [wheel](http://pythonwheels.com) rather than attempting to perform a backup of the cache folder.

Download the wheel for csselect of version 0.9.1 into `/tmp/wheelhouse`:

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=/tmp/wheelhouse cssselect==0.9.1
```

Install the downloaded wheel:

```
pip install /tmp/wheelhouse/cssselect-0.9.1-py2-none-any.whl
```

Comment: How stable/predictable is the `cssselect-0.9.1-py2-none-any.whl` file name?

Comment: Depends on what the maintainers are doing in their setup.py when packaging.

Answer (score 1):

Note that what pip caches is not necessarily human readable, and doing
`pip cache list` does not necessarily list all the files that have been cached in some fashion.  In addition to the .whl files that appear when you ask pip to list the cache, there is an `http` directory where network caching is done as well.  On linux, it is in `~/.cache/pip/http`.  Files there do not appear to be listed when you do `pip cache list`

If you ask pip to install comm==0.1.3, it will look in the regular cache and when the network request is made, it will look in the network cache under a hashed key.  The function _FileCacheMixin.encode() in the file pip/_internal/_vendor/cachecontrol/caches/file_cache.py (in pip version 23.0.1) turns the URL into a key.  On my machine, the key is '8856a20c..[etc]' and there is a file `~/.cache/pip/http/8/8/5/6/a/8856a2..[etc]` that is the whl file.

Upon attempting to install comm==0.1.3, pip will report:

```
Collecting comm==0.1.3
  Using cached comm-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
```

But `pip cache list | grep comm` comes up with nothing.  This is a known issue.  See: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10460

Answer (score 0):

Linux: ~/.cache/pip

MacOS: ~/Library/Caches/pip

Windows: %LocalAppData%\pip\Cache

Reference Docs: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/#where-is-the-cache-stored