# Can't see downloaded file after using pip download

Tags: python, pip

I am invoking `pip` commands from within my Python file. I am testing a simple download at the moment.

```
import pip

directory = 'C:/Users/me/Documents/tests'
package = 'psycopg2'

arguments = ['--only-binary=:all:', '--no-deps', '--platform',
             'manylinux1_x86_64', '--implementation', 'cp',
             '--abi', 'cp27mu', '--dest', directory, package]

def download():
    pip.main(['download'] + arguments)

download()
```

It successfully downloads it, but I cannot see the file in the directory. If I run it again, it even says:

```
File was already downloaded c:\users\me\documents\tests\psycopg2-2.7.3.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

**Edit**

When I try changing the directory, and re-download I get this message:

```
Using cached psycopg2-2.7.3.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

Sounds like it is saving it in some sort of temp directory instead of the specified one?

Comment: is the file hidden ?

Comment: That's what I thought but I can see hidden files so it can't be that.

Comment: Could you successfully run this command in terminal?

Comment: maybe it's using a cache directory? [where is pip cache folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41111916/1248974)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I opened the directory this morning, 2 days after I ran the program, to find the file inside. I re-ran the program and it worked just fine...

I guess even computers need the weekend to relax.