# where is the cached python package files for installation?

Tags: python, pip

e.g. for Ubuntu16.04 in virtualenv for python3.5
`$python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`
log shows something like:
`Collecting Cython==0.23.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))  Using cached Cython-0.23.4.zip`. However, when I use `$sudo find / -name Cython-0.23.4.zip` to find it there's nothing over there. Why? Where exactly are these cached zips and wheels? Thank u :)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578168/where-is-pip-cache-folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where is pip cache folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578168/where-is-pip-cache-folder)

Comment: My point is why I cannot find these source files anywhere using $find command.