# Unable to install pyautogui

Tags: python, pip, pyautogui

I'm trying to install Pyautogui on ubuntu 18.04, but I keep receiving the following error message:

```
$pip3 install pyautogui

Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/70/c5d340fadb06106135b7fe9677fc6d275f3cd7f7e6f896316c4cfe6c022c/PyAutoGUI-0.9.37.tar.gz
Collecting pymsgbox (from pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/65/86379ede1db26c40e7972d7a41c69cdf12cc6a0f143749aabf67ab8a41a1/PyMsgBox-1.0.6.zip
Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1 (from pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/f8/c32a58d6e4dff8aa5c27e907194d69f3b57e525c2e4af96f39c6e9c854d2/PyTweening-1.0.3.zip
Collecting Pillow (from pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/24/f53ff6b61b3d728b90934bddb4f03f8ab584a7f49299bf3bde56e2952612/Pillow-5.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting pyscreeze (from pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/6e/e175fda37d76d7846a6cda8a4364dfd7c2d343139b0716c4f03194d14933/PyScreeze-0.1.17.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-6aakksn1/pyscreeze/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6aakksn1/pyscreeze/
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyScreeze maintainer here. This is caused by a packaging error, which has been fixed in 0.1.18. It should work now if you install pyautogui, though you may have to delete [the pip cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578168/where-is-pip-cache-folder) on your machine first.

Answer (score 1):

The new release (v0.1.17) of pyscreeze fails to install as a dependency of pyautogui.

As a workaround try to install first the last working version of pyscreeze and after this pyautogui:

```
pip install pyscreeze<=0.1.14
pip install PyAutoGUI
```

I already created a new ticket for this issue https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/issues/37

Comment: I've already tried this before, but I keep receiving the same message!

Comment: Check your installed version of pyscreeze with pip list or try to install both in a new and fresh virtualenv

Comment: pip list shows me 'PyScreeze (0.1.14)'. But I'm going to try a virtualenv, thanks

Comment: Hm ... U used pip3 in your question, maybe your default Python Version differs?

Comment: I think I managed to solve this problem installing PyautoGui version 0.9.17. Any posterior version doesn't work for me and returns the same error message.