# How can I export installed libraries on Python to one install shell?

Tags: python, linux, pip, libraries, linux-distro

Recently, I'm changing Linux distro from PopOs to Ubuntu, and there is a lot of libraries installed by pip on Python that I want to bring on.
Could I migrate from these other distros, exporting and import all installed libraries on python? There's a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should read about the [pip cache system](https://www.techiediaries.com/python-pip-local-cache/) and how to enabled in different OS. If you already have a pip cache directory configured you can tell where is by:

```
pip cache dir
```

And then you could copy the content of your current cache dir to the one in your new distro.

References:

1. [Where is pip cache folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578168/where-is-pip-cache-folder)
2. [Pip cache documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_cache/)