# How to download packages from pypi using Wget?

Tags: virtualenv, wget, gnome-terminal

Where from should I download virtualenv to use `locally from source` using wget?

I'm having troubles downloading virtualenv from the command line.

Info: if you search for virtualenv you will find the site for the `stable` version and its installation guide which is just equals to the `latest` version installation guide.

To install locally it describe this :

***To install version X.X globally from source***:

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ [sudo] python setup.py install
```

***To use locally from source***:

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ python virtualenv.py myVE
```

- I'm using wget instead curl but should not be problem at all with this. Am I wrong?
- The only place where I can download it (and not from the command line) is from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/).
- I'm typing the url correctly.
- Different virtualenv versions at the url return the same not found:

  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
  2017-07-21 17:53:09 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Please note that I have already downloaded the tar.gz so I don't need it right now but I'm not sure if this is a broken link issue or I'm forgotten something else at the download command. I will not associate an issue to virtualenv just because a broken link but I need to know why this is not working.

EDIT: I can't download it using wget from `..python..packages/source/v/virtualenv` etc.

[image: Wget version]

Comment: Why not just `pip install virtualenv`?

Comment: 'cos I don't want to install pip or curl. It's not necessary at all. Virtualenv will provide pip

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I've written [a script which sounds suspiciously similar](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/blob/6cdfe1e44f65fb2ae37ba67c3bc985d8d9a44ae1/python/bootstrap_virtualenv.py)

Comment: Very nice. Let me try later your script. But of course I will change to the current version. What affraid is that the url return not found

Comment: Please don't add meta discussion or voting commentary to your questions, as that is confusing for new readers. The result is a reverse-order post that attempts to explain itself before the body. If you want to change a post so it looks like a question, try to write it as if it was the version you first wrote.

Comment: @halfer where is the meta discussion? I vote people who take a minute understanding or providing a useful answer. A meta discussion could be i.e. how stackoverflow shows the answers in order to theirs votes. I found useful their suggestions so I up vote the answer or the comment. I'm really tired of this... The usefulness comments, the anonymous down votes (apparently from high reputation users, but they don't answer the question, don't edit the question, don't and comments to make the question useful to others or for better answers).  This, my friend: is a comment for meta discussion

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my remark was not clear. "Meta discussion" means discussion about the question itself, rather than about the technical problem you are presenting. So, ask "how can I foo the bar using wget", rather than "In order to make a useful and constructive question-answer for everybody I had to modify the question, Just scroll down to the accepted answer, Or you can read the original description to understand...".

Comment: Thus my suggestion above is to keep questions focussed on question material, rather than discussions about presentation, voting, etc in the question itself. See my edit by way of more explanation. I agree that Stack Overflow takes a bit of getting used to (it has quite a critical approach to new questions and answers) but the end result is one of the best resources of tech Q&A on the web. That is no small feat, and of course you and I and millions of other people benefit from this, free of charge.

Comment: oh I understand now: You edited the question! You should have started by pointing that out. Thank you, looks really good

Comment: Any edits made to your posts are notified to you in your Stack Exchange inbox in the site header. There is no need for me to mention it as well. `:=)`

Comment: Thank you, I'll check the configuration just in case but I lost this one.. and again: you fixed the question perfectly thank you @halfer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TARGET="https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/"
PATTERN="virtualenv-15.1.0.tar.gz"

wget --recursive --no-directories --accept=$PATTERN $TARGET
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, curl and wget are equivalent for what you're trying.
2. No, you can download from anywhere. From [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/), e.g.
3. There is no functional difference between `pip install virtualenv` and what you're trying to do but the former is simpler and less error-prone so why bother with manual labour?

Comment: Phd thanks for your reply. I tried in another machine with curl and the url download the tar.gz. I'm probably using wrong wget, I mean maybe there is a parameter to download a tar.gz. I will search info about it as soon as possible (20minutes) but I have to say it, plus, thanks for your reply

Comment: Oh! I just see you wrote a link there. Awesome. Thanks

Comment: The why I want that (3) is because I'm trying to avoid any unnecessary issue. Pip and virtualenv both has warnings, pip warning is the mayor problem because virtualenv needs pip so I see this as recursive. I think that having locally will be fine and will not be so non-productive

Comment: By installing virtualenv manually not only you're doing unnecessary manual labour — you avoid pip caching and plant future problem (you'll need pip inside virtual envs so you'll have to do even more manual work). In short: you're doing it wrong. Instead of avoiding unnecessary issues you create them for yourself.

Comment: in this pc I'm using pip included in virtualenv which I installed through Debian's repos because the current version (15.1) is greater than the warned at installation's guide:1.9 and I forgot that when I ask this question trying to avoid to install by using just locally in another pc. Here you'll find an excellent `how to` related to caching packages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806448/how-do-i-install-from-a-local-cache-with-pip